# Redistribute a range of percentages according to a minimum value, while keeping relative proportions

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm, percentage

**FIDDLE HERE: http://jsfiddle.net/jakelauer/5S8t8/**

**What I need to do**

Loop through a range of percentages, which add up to 100%, and set any values that fall below a minimum threshold to a certain percentage, then redistribute the remaining percentages so that they are still the same relative to each other, so that the whole range still equals 100%.

**Why?**

I'm making a pie chart, and I need each value to show on the pie chart, even if it's a zero-value, so that it's still clickable. That means I need to set values below a certain threshold to a higher value, but I don't want to lose the relative proportions of the higher values, and they can't go over 100%

**Details**

Say I have a range of values:

```
var range = [190, 2453, 234, 14, 1244, 532, 0, 3, 1999];
```

and I convert these to percentage values, such that each value in the range becomes its percentage of the sum of the whole range, resulting in:

```
[0.02849002849002849, 0.36782126255810466, 0.03508771929824561, 0.002099265257159994, 0.18653471285050233, 0.07977207977207977, 0, 0.000449842555105713, 0.2997450892187734]
```

I want to loop through these percentages and set them to a minimum of `0.02`, or 2%. Here is the code I have so far:

```
var range = [190, 2453, 234, 14, 1244, 532, 0, 3, 1999];
var minimumPercent = 0.02;

function distributeRangeGivenMinimum(range, min) {
    var sum = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < range.length; i++) {
        sum += range[i];
    }

    var percents = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < range.length; i++) {
        percents.push(range[i] / sum);
    }

    var amtToSubtract = 0;
    var timesUnderMin = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < range.length; i++) {
        if (percents[i] < min) {
            amtToSubtract += (min - percents[i]);
            timesUnderMin++;
            percents[i] = min;
        }
    }

    var timesOverMin = percents.length - timesUnderMin;
    if (timesOverMin > 0) {
        for (var i = 0; i < range.length; i++) {
            if (percents[i] > min) {
                percents[i] = percents[i] - (amtToSubtract / timesOverMin);
            }
        }
    }

    return percents;
}
```

The problem with the above function is that, while it does accomplish the redistribution, it fails if any of the values are *just* above the minimum (e.g. if one of the values is 0.0201 and the minimum is 0.02, or something), they end up below the minimum after the redistribution, and I'm not sure how to solve that.

Comment: What do you mean by just above?

Comment: I mean barely over the minimum. For example, if a percentage ends up being 0.021, and the minimum is 0.02, it will likely end up lower than the minimum after redistribution.

Comment: You could iterate until no more values are under the minimum.  At each iteration, find values under the min, bump them up, find values over the min, rescale them by what's left after taking all the minimum ones from 100%.  May be easier if you divide the list into two lists: under and over.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following (new section is marked by comments):

```
var range = [190, 2453, 234, 14, 1244, 532, 0, 3, 1999];
var minimumPercent = 0.02;

function distributeRangeGivenMinimum(range, min) {
    var sum = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < range.length; i++) {
        sum += range[i];
    }

    var percents = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < range.length; i++) {
        percents.push(range[i] / sum);
    }

    var amtToSubtract = 0;
    var timesUnderMin = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < range.length; i++) {
        if (percents[i] < min) {
            amtToSubtract += (min - percents[i]);
            timesUnderMin++;
            percents[i] = min;
        }
    }

    var timesOverMin = percents.length - timesUnderMin;
    // begin new section
    do {
        var prevTimesOverMin = timesOverMin;
        var distSubAmt = amtToSubtract / timesOverMin;
        for (var i = 0; i < range.length; i++) {
            if (percents[i] > min && percents[i] - distSubAmt < min) {
                amtToSubtract -= (percents[i] - min);
                timesOverMin--;
                percents[i] = min;
            }
        }
    } while (timesOverMin != prevTimesOverMin);
    // end new section

    if (timesOverMin > 0) {
        for (var i = 0; i < range.length; i++) {
            if (percents[i] > min) {
                percents[i] = percents[i] - (amtToSubtract / timesOverMin);
            }
        }
    }

    return percents;
}
```